# rack for Kona Paddy Wagon

Tags: rack

I have a 2010 Kona Paddy Wagon which I use for commuting and I'm tired of riding with a heavy backpack (I need to carry a laptop). The bike has only one set of eyelets, which I currently use for mudguards.

If you Google around, there are some pictures of Paddy Wagons fitted with both mudguards and a rack, and they all look like using the same eyelets for both accessories.

Any Paddy Wagon owners here who use racks? How do you mount them to your bike? Do you use the same eyelets as for mudguards? Or maybe there are some other options?

Note that I don't want to use any racks attached to the seat post, they're not strong enough for my load.

Comment: The normal thing to do when you have only one set of eyelets but need a rack and mudguards is to use the eyelets for both the rack and the mudguards.  But this bike doesn't seem to have the rack mounts on the seat stays, so you'll end up using P-clamps or something. Look at Old Man Mountain's racks.

Comment: If you are worried about a seat post load then you need to be concerned with a fender load.  It was just designed for fenders.

Comment: Cheers guys. I'll be using the same eyelets for both. I took a closer look at them and they're actually made in such a way that permits mounting the fenders/mudguards on the inside of the tube, and the rack on the outside of the tube. As far as lack of rack mounts on the seatstays goes, I plan to go for Plescher Quick-Rack, which attaches to the seat post instead.